# Is it possible to apply a Linux kernel SECCOMP profile from a Go process?

Tags: go, system-calls, ptrace, seccomp

I am trying to implement an system call tracer with the support of [kernel SECCOMP](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.16/userspace-api/seccomp_filter.html) filters to reduce the overhead by filtering a few syscall types.

All the implementations I have found are in C, I am not able to figure how to map it to Go due to the special considerations with Go threading/go-routines and `fork()`.

The sample code (C):

```
if ((pid = fork()) == 0) {

    ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME, 0, 0, 0);
    /* To avoid the need for CAP_SYS_ADMIN */
    if (prctl(PR_SET_NO_NEW_PRIVS, 1, 0, 0, 0) == -1) {
        perror("prctl(PR_SET_NO_NEW_PRIVS)");
        return 1;
    }
    if (prctl(PR_SET_SECCOMP, SECCOMP_MODE_FILTER, &prog) == -1) {
        perror("when setting seccomp filter");
        return 1;
    }
    kill(getpid(), SIGSTOP);
    return execvp(argv[1], argv + 1);
```

After some research I have found that in order to perform a `fork()` like function in Go Lang we can use [syscall.ForkExec](https://golang.org/pkg/syscall/#ForkExec) or [exec.Command](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Command), but both seem to be limited to the set of pre-exec operations that can be configured through the parameter [syscall.SysProcAttr](https://golang.org/pkg/syscall/#SysProcAttr), while it provides support for the PTRACE_TRACEME call, it doesn't provide any support for the prctl() required for SECCOMP.

Is there some way to launch a "ptraceable" "seccomped" child process from a GoLang generated process ?

Comment: The reason you don't have metioned options is that you are looking at cross-platform library, and you search for Linux specific staff (Seccomp).
I haven't done what you are asking for, but found this: https://golang.org/pkg/syscall/#Syscall and example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43183700/544721 , maybe that's how you would like to approach it?

Comment: I did not had the requirement for a cross-platform library, I just did not found any suggestion to use the fork() syscall directly. I will give it a try. Can you please provide your comment as an answer ? If it works it properly addresses my question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two libraries one can use for this:

1. https://godoc.org/github.com/tfogal/ptrace - Package ptrace provides an interface to the ptrace system call.
2. https://godoc.org/github.com/seccomp/libseccomp-golang - Package seccomp provides bindings for libseccomp, a library wrapping the Linux seccomp syscall. Seccomp enables an application to restrict system call use for itself and its children.

Disclaimer: I am a c programmer, and have contributed to libseccomp; but golang is not my specialty so I am not sure what an equivalent of your sample code would be in that language.